# Populate an Array with Results from mySql Query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am having a problem with creating an array from the values received from a `mySql query`. I have the following code but I can't populate the array with the returned values. I assume that there is a problem with the `while` statement. Can anybody help me out?

```
$return_arr = array(); 

$searchTerm=$_GET['searchTerm'];
$query = "SELECT Actor.FirstName, Actor.LastName FROM Actors WHERE Actor.ActorFirstName LIKE '%$searchTerm%' ";

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
$stmt->bind_result($firstName, $lastName);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($stmt) {
    $return_arr[] =  $row['FirstName'];
}
```

Comment: you are overriding your array variable try to append into array not reassign the array

Comment: let's say you have a var called a

if you say a="something" 

it will be always something but if you say 
a+="something" it will just appends something in the end i hope this gives you an idea

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php instead

Comment: it seems you are mixing mysqli OO style with procedural style, stick with one of the two style and it should work http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-result-examples

Comment: Don't even think about using mysql_

Comment: @nikoss you are mistaken. `[]` is the standard method for building arrays

Answer (score 0):

change your while loop

while($stmt->fetch())

{

$return_arr[] =  $firstName;

}